# Can't upgrade mysql to 64 bit

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, 64-bit, mysql

I have downloaded the DMG from the [mysql website](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) for the 64-bit install, and installed successfully. Yet after installation, when I run

```
mysql --version
```

I get:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.52, for apple-darwin10.3.0 (i386) using readline 5.1
```

Which seems to me to indicate the 32-bit version is installed. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, what gives is that your OS X kernel is running in 32-bit. Check using `uname -m`. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934/how-come-a-32-bit-kernel-can-run-a-64-bit-binary/49951#49951). However, applications may run in 64-bit. Use `file` on your mysql binary. For example, a universal binary would come up as:

```
$ file /usr/bin/tar
/usr/bin/tar: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
/usr/bin/tar (for architecture x86_64): Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/tar (for architecture i386):   Mach-O executable i386
/usr/bin/tar (for architecture ppc7400):    Mach-O executable ppc
```

A 64-bit binary (installed using MacPorts):

```
$ file /opt/local/bin/python
/opt/local/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Comment: You're right, my kernel is running in 32-bit mode. How do I change that?

Comment: Here is an article about how to do so: http://macperformanceguide.com/SnowLeopard-64bit.html